# Property of Composite Key Not Found

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity @Table @Audited
public class MyParent {

    @Id
    @Column
    Integer id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.myParent", orphanRemoval = true)
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL })
    List<Child> children;
}

@Entity @Table @Audited
public class Child {

    @EmbeddedId
    ChildId id = new ChildId();
}

@Embeddable
public class ChildId implements Serializable {

    @MapsId("my_parent")
    @JoinColumn(name = "my_parent_id") 
    @ManyToOne
    MyParent myParent;
    @Column
    String name;
}
```

Before I added the annotation `@Audited` everything worked fine. Afterwards everything failed because Hibernate 5.1 did not like composite keys (see [HHH-7625](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7625)).

It took forever, but I managed to update to 5.2 just now, and now everything works... except for auditing. I get the following exception:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: myParent_id of: org.acme.project.Child_AUD [select e__ from org.acme.project.Child_AUD e__ where e__.myParent_id = :myParent_id and e__.originalId.REV.id = (<removed internal query>)]

I used this code:

```
AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(this.em);
MyParent parent = auditReader .find(MyParent.class, id, revision);
parent.getChildren(); // exception is here
```

So where does Envers get `myParent_id` from? I'm not sure. I tried to rename the column `my_parent_id` to that ID, but it did nothing.

And I tried to replace `ChildId.myParent` with an ID, but that does not help either.

[This paragraph](https://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/#exceptions-onetomanyjoincolumn) in the documentation looks eerily similar, but I don't know what I should do based on what it says.

Am I missing something? Or is this yet another bug? How do I get the code to work?

Comment: Have you tried `@AuditMappedBy(mappedBy = "id.myParent")` on the `@OneToMany` mapping in `MyParent` to see if that helps influence Envers?

Comment: @Naros  Yes, then the exception is: "@AuditMappedBy points to a property that doesn't exist: org.acme.project.Child.id.myParent"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further review, this is a known problem reported as [HHH-11770](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11770) which has since been fixed and is included in the 5.2.11.Final Hibernate Envers release.

The underlying problem is that `OneAuditedEntityQueryGenerator` only had support for when the reference pointed to an `@IdClass` but did not support the use case for `@EmbeddedId`.

You can either use the latest snapshot for `hibernate-envers` if you cannot wait for the official release of 5.2.11.Final or you can integrate the code change yourself using this [commit](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/a7f77e2687067c2b1529d12392771e0a38ba92a1).

If you do decide to use the latest snapshot, I do advise you apply the snapshot for ORM too.